# How do i retrieve data from table using group by having foll0wing condition

Tags: mysql, database

List of all countries having more than 2 COVID-19 affected males.

```
select * from country
where country_id in(select country_id 
                    from(select country_id, count(*)
                        from person
                        where Gender="Male" 
                        and virus_id=(select virus_id 
                                        from virus 
                                        where virus_name="crona_virus"
                                    )
                        group by country_id
                        having count(*)>2
                        )as tbl
                    );
```

I do get the results but those are not desired.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Two things: First, indent your code in a meaningful way, so we can read it and your future self can read it. Second, it will help us help you if you describe what's wrong with your results. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Judging by all those unnecessary sub queries you may not be familiar with joins see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html BTW corona virus not crona virus - may be your only problem

Answer (score 0):

IN could be replaced by join and sub queries replaced by join

```
select country.* 
from country
join
(select country_id, count(*)
 from person
 join virus on person.virus_id = virus.virus_id and virus_name = 'corona_virus'
 group by country_id  having count(*)>2
)as tbl
on country.country_id = tbl.country_id;
```